How to use a class to add and remove values to / from cookies in Ruby on Rails?
The users of my Rails app tend to have multiple accounts to login. Cookies are used to store the names of those accounts in each user's browser as comma separated values. This makes it easier for my users to switch between accounts.
I created a helper module to handle all the dirty work related to cookies:
module StoredAccountsHelper

  def store_account(account)
    names = stored_accounts.unshift(account.name)
    cookies.permanent[:accounts] = names.uniq.join(',')
  end

  def discard_accounts
    cookies.delete(:accounts)
  end

  def stored_accounts
    cookies[:accounts]&.split(',') || []
  end

  def account_options
    stored_accounts&.sort&.map
  end

  def only_one_stored_account?
    stored_accounts.count == 1
  end

end

This helper works and has stood the test of time, however it feels wrong to me. Shouldn't all the methods be methods of a class (e.g. named AccountsStore) rather than those of a helper module?
That way, I could do things like:
accounts_store = AccountsStore.new(@account)
accounts_store.add(@account)
accounts_store.remove(@account)
accounts_store.list_all
accounts_store.options

etc.
But unfortunately, cookies can only be used in controllers and helpers if I am informed correctly.
Is there a more elegant logic to add values to and remove values from a cookie in Rails?

First of all, yes, helpers sucks and should not exist at all (I am willing to die on that hill). Your design is much cleaner, instead of @account simply give it a store and pass cookies object from the controller and you're done. This way you can switch to a different store in the future as well (I am not sure cookies are the best way to handle this, I'd probably keep it inside the db instead)

This is gonna be a long one but bear with me. Rails is really just a stack of Rack middleware and apps stacked on top of each other. A core concept in Rack is the env hash that each piece of middleware passes on as a argument to the next component. It's just a normal hash that contains information about the request and can be used by middleware to pass anything down the line.
ActionDispatch::Cookies is one such middleware which decodes the cookies from the headers into the cookie jar before the request is processed by the router. This is then passed down the Rack stack in the env hash, through the router which then calls your controller which is a Rack compliant app.
The controller thus has access to the cookies and any information about the request because it was called with a the env hash by the router. It then provides this to your helpers and views via accessor methods that are callable through the view context.
If you want other classes to have information about the request you need to pass it into the class (or make it into some sort of global - yuck).
class AccountsStore
  def initialize(cookies, current_account: nil)
    @cookies = cookies
  end

  def add(account) 
    # ...
  end
end

class ApplicationController
  # ...
  private

  def accounts
    @accounts ||= AccountsStore.new(cookies)
  end
end

This pattern is known as Constuctor Injection.
But if you're going through these steps why not actually make it into middleware so that it's actually available throughout the stack like for example in the router?
class AccountsStoreMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end
  def call(env)
    env['my_app.account_store'] = AccountsStore.new(env['action_dispatch.cookies'])
    app.call env
  end
end

# config/application.rb
config.middleware.insert_after ActionDispatch::Cookies, AccountsStoreMiddleware

That's how Warden (the foundation of Devise) for example handles authentication and how the Apartment gem handles multi-tenancy.

You're right in that a using a helper is a working but smelly solution. It moves the code out of your controller (or it's superclass) into another file but the responsibility isn't actually moved. You're just tucking the code away into the smelly armpits of Rails.

Why you can't just create an abstraction that holds many accounts and store that abstraction_id in the cache.
So for example you can just:
abstraction.accounts << new_account

